# Bugzilla urlBase parameter is not working

Tags: bugzilla

bydefault my bugzilla is loaded on

```
localhost
```

but I want it to load on

```
bugs.mycompanyname.com/bugzilla
```

I tried pasting this url in "urlBase" parameter but it doesn't load.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already created the DNS bugs.mycompanyname.com? If yes, the DNS is pointing to the machine where you installed your bugzilla?

Note that bugs.mycompanyname.com/bugzilla won't work, just bugs.mycompanyname.com should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14573000)

Comment: From my point of view it helps a lot the person who have asked. Because I have had the same problem and I resolved it by following the steps that presented on my answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be helpful to anyone but it's still a comment and not a full-blown, well-structured answer.